# etherscan.io says a sig is valid but i can't get ethereumjs to say that that same sig is valid

Tags: ethereumjs, signature, cryptography, ecrecover

I'm trying to use ethereumjs to verify a signature. The signature verifies successfully with https://etherscan.io/verifySig using the following parameters:

- **[Step 1] Address**: 0x817A8d457bF4bFcDB833a0C72eb2f879C857e1E5
- **[Step 2] Message Signature Hash**: 0xa3ea6f0c3302f82103a62bb31bdbd9ea5a25436d2a3414d0cb1f60e7fc8cf0fb337c1205ad5e6180015e1fbb9fecffe956e519b6f4af79a08df7a1275fb8abc71c
- **[Step 3] Enter the original message that was signed**: lol:18006416246562465

Unfortunately, it's not verifying with ethereumjs. Here's my code:

```
import { ecrecover, pubToAddress } from 'ethereumjs-util'

var signature = "a3ea6f0c3302f82103a62bb31bdbd9ea5a25436d2a3414d0cb1f60e7fc8cf0fb337c1205ad5e6180015e1fbb9fecffe956e519b6f4af79a08df7a1275fb8abc71c";
var message = 'lol:18006416246562465';

var messageBuffer = new Buffer(message, 'hex');

var r = new Buffer(signature.substring(0, 64), 'hex')
var s = new Buffer(signature.substring(64, 128), 'hex')
var v = new Buffer((parseInt(signature.substring(128, 130)) + 27).toString());

var pub = ecrecover(messageBuffer, v, r, s);
var recoveredAddress = '0x' + pubToAddress(pub).toString('hex')

console.log(recoveredAddress);
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
        throw new Error('Invalid signature v value');
              ^

Error: Invalid signature v value
    at ecrecover (C:\path\to\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist\signature.js:50:15)
    at file:///C:/path/to/test.js:23:11
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

In reviewing the ethereumjs-util source code I see that it's throwing that exception because the following function is returning false:

```
function isValidSigRecovery(recovery) {
    const rec = new externals_1.BN(recovery);
    return rec.eqn(0) || rec.eqn(1);
}
```

When I do `console.log(rec.toString())` I get `12829` back.

So how is etherscan.io verifying the sig when I can't?

Comment: Try `v = parseInt(sig.substring(128, 130), 16);`.

I'm not sure why you're converting v to a string or adding 27.

Comment: v has to be 0 or 1, you have to something like var `v = signature.substring(128, 130) == "1b" ? 0 : 1`

Comment: @0xCourtney - I was basing my code off of https://gist.github.com/OR13/08e2ceba147b52ef078c4527e1c48a25 . But your comment helped! As did Ismael's. Thanks!

Comment: I know this has already been answered however, I just wrote a blog post about signatures that you may find useful.

https://www.theweb3dev.com/blog/on-chain-authentication